# How to filter string vector by matching with another sequence of strings?

Tags: r, lapply

How to filter string vector by matching with another sequence of strings? Notice I'm supposed to run this on a large vector so this is just a simple example and the the `|` delimated string is obtained from `paste(ids,collapse="|")`. Here's an example:

```
> lapply(c("6:26762428[b38]","1:10177[b38]","1:10235[b38]"), function(x) grepl(x, c("6:26762428[b38]|6:27333733[b38]|14:105766248[b38]")))
[[1]]
[1] FALSE

[[2]]
[1] FALSE

[[3]]
[1] FALSE
```

The above should return `TRUE, FALSE, FALSE`. Also it's better to be optimized for speed.

Comment: Use `fixed = TRUE` i.e `lapply(c("6:26762428[b38]","1:10177[b38]","1:10235[b38]"), function(x) grepl(x, c("6:26762428[b38]|6:27333733[b38]|14:105766248[b38]"), fixed = TRUE))`

Comment: Thanks! @akrun what does this mean?

Comment: `[` is metacharacter

Comment: is'nt `|` a metacharacter too? I thought things could go wrong if we used `fixed=TRUE` with `|`. Always leraning from @akrun